# Where do magic constants for signature algorithms come from?

Tags: hash, digital-signature

For example, I've seen `3031300d060960864801650304020105000420` as an identifier for RSA/SHA256, `3020300c06082a864886f70d020505000410` for RSA/MD5. Where do these values come from?

I ran into one of these values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524198/what-version-of-openssl-is-needed-to-sign-with-sha256withrsaencryption/11117338#11117338), where it said:

```
$t = '3031300d060960864801650304020105000420'; # sha256
```

and [here](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/signature_8c-source.html#l01273):

```
case PGPHASHALGO_SHA256:
    t = stpcpy(t, " RSA/SHA256");
    prefix = "3031300d060960864801650304020105000420";
```

Comment: Please add references for *I've seen*, especially proving that you have seen specific values more than once (otherwise the question would be of little use).

Answer (score 2):

Of course writing the question led me to the answer...

These values come from [RFC3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-43):

```
For the six hash functions mentioned in Appendix B.1, the DER
encoding T of the DigestInfo value is equal to the following:

MD2:     (0x)30 20 30 0c 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 02 05 00 04
               10 || H.
MD5:     (0x)30 20 30 0c 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 05 05 00 04
               10 || H.
SHA-1:   (0x)30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14 || H.
SHA-256: (0x)30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00
               04 20 || H.
SHA-384: (0x)30 41 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 02 05 00
               04 30 || H.
SHA-512: (0x)30 51 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 03 05 00
                  04 40 || H.
```

Comment: Well, they do not strictly *come from* that list, they come from the definition of the `DigestInfo` structure, the OIDs defined for certain algorithms, and the DER for ASN.1 encoding. But some programmers indeed may have simply copied from this list.

Comment: Got a reference for them?